# Does proximity matter when hooking up batteries?

Tags: batteries, serial

I'm planning to put two batteries in both feet of a two-legged robot and then creating a serial connection of the two sets using wires up to the hips. My question is, does this effect the power source in any way? Is it important to have the 4 batteries serially connected as close as possible?

Comment: The farther apart they are, the longer the wire connecting them. The longer the wire, the fatter it needs to be to avoid unwanted voltage drop. The longer and fatter the wire, the heavier the robot and the more expensive the wire. I don't think there is any other major drawback to distance. You will want to consider the effects of flexing on the wire. Use extra fine stranded wire (similar to lamp cord) if you want to maximize the life of the wire. Don't use stiff wire.

Comment: How do I calculate the voltage drop? It's only a few inches of wire connecting AA batteries.

Comment: For a few inches, and AA batteries, there should be little need to worry about voltage drop - #18 lamp cord should be sufficient.  There are copper wire tables that will give the resistance per some length, usually for 1000 ft.  Use Ohm's Law with the current you expect to draw to determine the voltage drop in the cable.

Comment: And the longer it is, the higher the inductance as well, meaning more bulk capacitance near the electronics.

Comment: @MichaelRader
You can calculate the voltage drop across the wire using ohms law as stated above. You can also *measure* the voltage drop using a multimeter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every piece of wire you add in a circuit, acts like a resistor. Ohm's Law kicks in when that wire is carrying any non-trivial amount of current, causing voltage droop. You're adding a few ohms of resistance. You can minimize and measure it by taking the wire size (in AWG), and looking up the resistance for the length of your cable (Plenty of handy calculators online like [this one](http://www.powerstream.com/Wire_Size.htm)).

For example, adding 2 feet of 20 AWG wire, which has 10.15Ω per **1000 ft**, *would only add 0.0203Ω of resistance*. Your  At low voltage and/or current, that's fairly negligible, so you shouldn't have any problems. *Consider a AA battery might have a Internal Resistance of 0.1Ω!* Physically bigger wire has a lower resistance.

Comment: Just a general comment. The lower the voltage, the more important it is to not have large voltage drops. In an AA battery circuit, a drop of 0.01V is usually OK, but a drop of 0.1V could be a fairly big deal in terms of battery life. But good answer overall.

Comment: Of course, but for 0.02 ohms you need 5 amps for that drop. With AA battery ESR at 0.1 ohm, you get a 0.1V drop at 1 amp. The wire is still negligible here.

Comment: Definitely. My comment was not intended as a criticism of your answer, really. Jut further information for other people who find this answer using a search engine, and who might have a slightly different situation.